# Bot Framework Read UserState data outside of dialog or resume to conversation dialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a PizzaBot. After getting the order I save the data to the UserState. After that the user gets a button(ActionTypes.OpenUrl) to pay the order on a different system. Everything works fine till now.

However, when the payment service call my api, I cannot get the UserState data anymore. I have tried to send a Proactive notification, the "You have paid successfully" message is being shown, but I cannot retrieve UserData.

I get my conversation id conversationReference, but I have no idea what I should call in the BotCallback to resume to the conversation.

```
foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
{
    await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default);
}
```

Do you have any example of that for me?

Comment: As far as I remember, you need to persist state in remote storage. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.userstate?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

and example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#add-state-property-accessors

Comment: I don't want to save user data to database at all, I just want to collect that in the bot send  to order system after payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue thanks to George.

On the UserState documentation page this is written:

> User state is available in any turn that the bot is conversing with
> that user on that channel, regardless of the conversation.

This means if my NotificationController is called the UserState is there somewhere.
So, I have created a proactive MainDialog on the BotCallback with an option: see: [Starting A Dialog From From A Proactive Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371053/starting-a-dialog-from-from-a-proactive-message) and read UserState data if the option is filled and coming from my NotificationController