# Start a Dialog after a proactive message

Tags: botframework

I'm currently using this sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages and the proactive messages are working fine, but I want to start a dialog that i'm already have. I dont know how to call an specific dialog after send the proactive message

My controller which trigger the proactive message:

```
[Route("api/statutory")]
[ApiController]
public class StatutoryController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
    private readonly string _appId;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;

    private readonly BotState _userState;
    private readonly BotState _conversationState;

    public StatutoryController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IConfiguration configuration, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences, ConversationState conversationState,
    UserState userState)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
        _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
        _appId = configuration["MicrosoftAppId"] ?? string.Empty;

        _conversationState = conversationState;
        _userState = userState;

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
        {
            await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));
        }



        // Let the caller know proactive messages have been sent
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = "<html><body><h1>Statutory Reconciliation Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>",
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        };
    }

    private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("We are preparing your spreadsheet please wait...");
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Your reconciled spreadsheet is ready, please click on the download link");

       //at here o want to call a dialog, somenthing like this: 
       //var StatutoryDialog = new StatutoryReconciliationDialog();
       //await turnContext.StartDialog(StatutoryDialog);
```

I see some other threads here at stack overflow about this subject, but they are from almost 2 years ago and some of the codes are different now in the samples. I will be trully grateful if someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you said code had changed, but have you checked out this answer? It seems to be very similar to your code, and you should be able to update your `BotCallback` function to start a dialog. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371053/starting-a-dialog-from-from-a-proactive-message

Comment: @billoverton thanks for your response, i tried to follow this example, but it didnt worked for me, im trying to undestand how i properly start a dialog, i just need to instance de dialog class and run it? like 

var SDialog = new StatutoryDialog();
await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(sDialog), cancellationToken);

I keep reading the documentation and this examples, but neither of this is working for mu case. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Hi, I'm curious, I don't get to understand what you're trying to achieve, could you elaborate a bit, please. My main doubt here is that you (usually) begin a dialog when the turn begins, that is, when the user sends a message, but a proactive message is sent to the conversation without the user sending anything at this point (but the conversation must have been already started by the user)

Comment: Thank you @MiguelVeloso for you anwser.I have already implemented a dialog that occurs when the user prompts "Statutory Reconciliation", let's call it the Statutory Reconciliation Dialog. This dialog works correctly and without problems. In some cases (events of specific dates for example) I would like the bot to proactively warn the user of this process. It would warn the user (perhaps asking if the user wants to proceed) and trigger the Statutory Reconciliation Dialog. If I am not clear enough please let me know that I can try to elaborate further. Again Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, that's clear enough, what you'd do is send the user a proactive message, for example a HeroCard with options, and when the user confirms that they want to do whatever, which is a new message from the user, then you begin the new dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a few days i figured out how to fix this problem.

First you need to change your bot class, in this case i changed my "ProactiveBot.cs"

from this:

```
ProactiveBot: ActivityHandler
```

to this:

```
ProactiveBot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Dialog
```

After that i just create a local variable of the current context instance and begin the dialog. I do this in the proactive controller, afeter send the message

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("We are preparing your spreadsheet please wait...");

var dc = await new DialogSet(null).CreateContextAsync(turnContext);
await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(StatutoryDialog));
```

Where "StatutoryDialog" is the name of you dialog class.